# How to disable specific tab in ttk::notebook

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Need to disable particular tab, when user select the other one. I am not able to achieve it using following code.

Tab still remains enabled. also tried `configure -state disabled` but throwing error.

```
ttk::notebook .top.d -padding 5
ttk::frame .top.d.f1;
ttk::frame .top.d.f2;
.top.d add .top.d.f2 -text "East" -padding 5
.top.d add .top.d.f1 -text "West" -padding 5
.top.d select .top.d.f1
ttk::notebook::enableTraversal .top.d
.top.d index .top.d.f2
##set vf [ttk::frame .top.d.f1]
bind .top.d <<NotebookTabChanged>> {
    if {[.top.d select] == ".top.d.f2"} {
        set flag 2
        .top.d.f1  state disabled
        puts $flag
    }
}
```

Please suggest correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
.top.d tab .top.d.f1 -state disabled
```

(The path name is one of the ways to identify a tab; index number could be used as well.)

Documentation: [ttk::notebook](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_notebook.htm)