# How to "gray out" or disable tabs in ttkNotebook?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, ttk

I am going through the ttk notebook manual found [here](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_notebook.htm#M21), but I cannot seem to find something that would do the affect stated in the title. The closest thing I see is the hide tab option, but I would like for it to be disabled instead of hidden. Is there a way to achieve in this in tcl/tk, specifically in an R setting?

Comment: answered here: [Need to disable particular tab, when user select the other one. I am not able to achieve it using following code...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537245/how-to-disable-specific-tab-in-ttknotebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every tab of a notebook has a **-state** option (as well as several for controlling the contents of the tab itself), which can be `normal` (the default), `hidden` (which conceals the tab entirely) or `disabled` (the tab is there but cant be chosen, and is visually disabled too). You want that last option. These options are configured through the **tab** method of the notebook widget or are given when you **add** the tab.

```
$nb tab $tab -state disabled
```

The `$tab` (for the **tab** method) can be either the name of the slave widget that is the body of the tab, or the index within the tab list. (Or a few other things that probably aren't so useful to you.)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how this is implemented in the R package? The documentation is very sparse, and I do not see how the tcl/tk translates to R

Answer (score 2):

the appropriate documentation link would be:

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_notebook.htm

and the following command as well:

> *pathname* **tab** *tabid* ?*-option* ?*value* ...??

e.g.

```
.win.fNB.nb tab .win.fNB.nb.f4 -state disabled
```

Comment: You actually link to the same page; we use both domains (and prefer the `tcl-lang.org` one) because of long-term management issues with the `.tk` registrar.